# Is there a way to use gulp-typescript to generate both map and declaration files during one compilation task?

Tags: typescript, gulp, gulp-sourcemaps, tsconfig, gulp-typescript

I am using [gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript) to transpile my TypeScript code to JavaScript. Essentially, I want for one `*.ts` file, for there to be corresponding `*.js`, `*.d.ts` and `*.map` files generated.

In the compile task, I have noticed that I can only transpile with declaration **or** transpile with map but not both at the same time. For example, having 1 compile task that attempts to generate both declaration + map files (with the JavaScript files) like the following does not work. The following will generate the JavaScript + map files, but not the declaration files.

```
var tsc = require('gulp-typescript');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var tsProject = tsc.createProject('tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('compile', function () {
  var tsProject = tsc.createProject('tsconfig.json');
  var tsResult = gulp.src(['src/**/*.ts'])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(tsProject());
  return tsResult.js
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/src'));
});
```

My `tsconfig.json` looks like the following.

```
{
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "diagnostics": false,
        "listEmittedFiles": false,
        "listFiles": false,
        "pretty": true,
        "declaration": true
    }
}
```

To work around this problem, for now, I have to create 3 gulp tasks:

- one to create the declarations,
- one to create the mapping, and
- one to call on the previous two.

This option works, but is not desired, or best practice, as now I have to compile twice just to get the desired outputs.

My 3 gulp tasks look like the following. Note how I have made `tsProject` local to the functions now (keeping it global, the gulp task fails).

```
gulp.task('compile:with:dts', function () {
  var tsProject = tsc.createProject('tsconfig.json');
  return gulp.src(['src/**/*.ts'])
    .pipe(tsProject())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/src'));
});

gulp.task('compile:with:maps', function () {
  var tsProject = tsc.createProject('tsconfig.json');
  var tsResult = gulp.src(['src/**/*.ts'])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(tsProject());
  return tsResult.js
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/src'));
});

gulp.task('compile', ['compile:with:dts', 'compile:with:maps']);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two streams in your example:

- `tsResult` which contains the typings files
- `tsResult.js` which contains the transpiled JavaScript files

All you have to do is merge them into one stream using [`merge-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream):

```
var tsc = require('gulp-typescript');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var merge = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('compile', function () {
  var tsProject = tsc.createProject('tsconfig.json');
  var tsResult = gulp.src(['src/**/*.ts'])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(tsProject());
  return merge(tsResult, tsResult.js)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/src'));
});
```

Comment: `tsResult` contains both sets of files. `tsResult.js` just the js files, `tsResult.dts` just the dts files.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this approach:

```
const gulp = require("gulp")
const ts = require("gulp-typescript")
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps')
const tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json")
const merge = require('merge2')

gulp.task("compile", () => {
    const tsResult = 
            tsProject.src()  // OR: gulp.src(['src/**/*.ts'])
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(tsProject())

    return merge([
        tsResult.dts.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/types')),
        tsResult.js.pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    ]);
})
```

See:

https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript#basic-usage